# Help with removing duplicates

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I have asked a similar question 6 months ago that still has not been answer or any suggestions made.

Here is the problem.  The code below is returning duplicate records.
The actual returned record set I am working with is the Model.Product.
The query is looking at the DateAdded field within ProductSkus table to see if the Product should show.
The only problem is if more then 1 ProductSkus match the requirement for a particular Product I get duplicate records.  I can't have this.
I only care about accessing the data contained in Model.Product.  Not Model.Product.ProductSkus.

Has anyone ran into a similar situation?
Any ideas on how to get the results I am looking for?

Thanks in advance.

```
ICriteria query = this.Session.CreateCriteria<Model.Product>();
query.CreateAlias("ProductSkus", "ProdSku", JoinType.InnerJoin)
     .AddOrder(new Order("ProdSku.DateAdded", false))
     .AddOrder(new Order("Name", true))
     .Add(Restrictions.Ge("ProdSku.DateAdded", myDate))
     .SetMaxResults(100);
```

result = query.List();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make sure that your query/criteria uses a 'resultransformer'.  In this case, you'll need the DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer.

```
 query.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity);
```

Next to that, how is that association mapped ?  Is it mapped as a bag, or as a set ?

Comment: It is mapped as a bag.  Your suggestion worked.  Thank you so very much.